# Acceder a métodos de objetos en un ArrayList parametrizado sin casting

Tags: java

Me encuentro realizando unas prácticas de Java, pero tengo un problema, o duda más bien. He creado una clase llamada Lista(que adjuntaré más adelante), la cual es parametrizada, con un `ArrayList`, es decir, que dicho `ArrayList` aceptará objetos del tipo indicado en la declaración del objeto Lista.

El problema viene a la hora de acceder a métodos del objeto que la compone. En este caso, de objetos Articulo. 
Intento acceder a ellos mediante:

```
lista.get(pedirPosicion()).incrementarExistencias()
```

Pero Eclipse me dice que el método, en el ejemplo `incrementarExistencias().`, no está definido para el tipo `Object` y solo puedo realizar la acción realizando el casting de esta manera

```
(Articulo) listarticulos.get(index)).decrementarExistencias()
```

Si la clase y el ArrayList está parametrizado, es decir que uso Generics, ¿no debería poder utilizarlo sin dicho casting?

Os muestro el código de las clases para  explicar mejor la situación.

**Clase Lista.**

```
package listadoestructuras3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Lista<E> {

    ArrayList<E> lista=null;

    public Lista(){
        lista=new ArrayList<E>();
    }
    public boolean add(E articulo){
        if(articulo==null)
            return false;

        if(lista.contains(articulo))
            return false;

        lista.add(articulo);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean removeWithObject(E e){
        return lista.remove(e);
    }   

    public boolean removeWithIndex(int index){
        if(index < 0 || index >= size())
            return false;
        lista.remove(index);
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<E> getLista(){
        return lista;
    }

    public E get(int index){
        if(index < 0 || index >= size())
            return null;
        return lista.get(index);

    }

    public int size() {
        return lista.size();
    }

}
```

Y la clase **Articulo**.

```
package listadoestructuras3;

public class Articulo {

    private String nombre;
    private int num_existencias;
    private int num_minimo_existencias;

    public Articulo(String  nombre, int numexistencias, int num_minimo_existencias){
        setNombre(nombre);
        setNumexistencias(numexistencias);
        setNumMinimoExistencias(num_minimo_existencias);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((nombre == null) ? 0 : nombre.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Articulo other = (Articulo) obj;
        if (nombre == null) {
            if (other.nombre != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!nombre.equals(other.nombre))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int getNumMinExistencias() {
        return num_minimo_existencias;
    }

    public void setNumMinimoExistencias(int num_minimo_existencias) {
        this.num_minimo_existencias = num_minimo_existencias;
    }

    public void consumir(int cantidad){
        setNumexistencias(GetNumExistencias()-cantidad);
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int GetNumExistencias() {
        return num_existencias;
    }

    public void setNumexistencias(int numexistencias) {
        this.num_existencias = numexistencias;
    }

    public void comprarExistencias(int compra){
        setNumexistencias(GetNumExistencias()+compra);
    }

    public void modificarExistencias(int num){
        setNumMinimoExistencias(num);
    }

    public void incrementarExistencias(){
        setNumexistencias(GetNumExistencias()+1);
    }

    public void decrementarExistencias(){
        setNumexistencias(GetNumExistencias()-1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return getNombre() + ".Existencias: " + GetNumExistencias() + ". N.Minimo Existencias: " + getNumMinExistencias() + "\n";
    }

}
```

Y finalmente, la clase Test donde intento acceder a los métodos a través de la lista, donde se ve que tengo que realizar los casting.

```
package listadoestructuras3;
import utiles.Menu;
import utiles.Teclado;

public class TestListaCompra {
    static Lista listacompra = new Lista<Articulo>();
    static Lista listarticulos = new Lista<Articulo>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Menu menu = new Menu("Pila",
                new String[] {"Añadir articulo","Eliminar articulo","Incrementar existencias articulo","Decrementar existencias articulo","Modificar existencia minima articulo","Mostrar lista productos","Mostrar lista de la compra"});
        int opcion;
        do {
            opcion = menu.gestionar();
            gestionar(opcion);
        } while (opcion != menu.getSalir());
    } 

    public static void gestionar(int opcion) {
        int index;
        switch(opcion) {
            case 1:
                if(!listarticulos.add(new Articulo(pedirNombre(), pedirNumExistencia(),pedirNumExistencia())))
                    System.err.println("No se ha podido añadir");
                break;
            case 2:
                if(!listarticulos.removeWithIndex(pedirPosicionLista()))
                    System.err.println("No se ha podido añadir");
                break;
            case 3:
                index = pedirPosicionLista();
                ((Articulo) listarticulos.get(index)).incrementarExistencias();
                if(((Articulo) listarticulos.get(index)).GetNumExistencias()>=((Articulo) listarticulos.get(index)).getNumMinExistencias())
                    listacompra.removeWithObject(listarticulos.get(index));     
                break;
            case 4:
                index = pedirPosicionLista();
                ((Articulo) listarticulos.get(index)).decrementarExistencias();
                if(((Articulo) listarticulos.get(index)).GetNumExistencias()<((Articulo) listarticulos.get(index)).getNumMinExistencias())
                    listacompra.add(listarticulos.get(index));
                break;  
            case 5:
                ((Articulo) listarticulos.get(pedirPosicionLista())).modificarExistencias(pedirNumExistencia());
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println(listarticulos.getLista());
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println(listacompra.getLista());
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }

    public static String pedirNombre(){
        return Teclado.leerCadena("Introduce el nombre del articulo");
    }

    public static int pedirNumExistencia(){
        int num=0;
        do{
             num = Teclado.leerEntero("Introduce el numero de existencias");    
        }while(num<=0);
        return num;    
    }

    public static int pedirPosicionLista(){
        int posicion=0;
//      do{
            posicion=Teclado.leerEntero("Introduce una posicion");
        //}while(posicion<0 || posicion>equipo.getTamañoLista()-1);
        return posicion;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sí está usando genéricos para Java , efectivamente no es necesario realizar el `cast` , pero dependerá de como cree e inicialice la Lista en donde la use, es por eso que se ve forzado a realizar el `cast` porque está mal creada la Lista al inicio de su programa *(no especifica el tipo)*

```
static Lista listarticulos = new Lista<Articulo>();
```

Cambiar por ... , especificando el tipo de Elemento , que será en este caso la clase `Articulo`

```
static Lista<Articulo> listarticulos = new Lista<>();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me estaba volviendo un poco loco y no me fijé en esto, que era lo más obvio. Gracias!

Comment: @Mario Genial , Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

```
static Lista listacompra = new Lista<Articulo>();
static Lista listarticulos = new Lista<Articulo>();
```

Estas inicializando mas las listas no estas diciendo de que tipo de listas son , como usas generics debes especificar que tipo de dato es la lista.

```
static Lista<Articulo> listarticulos = new Lista<>(Articulo);
static Lista<Articulo> listacompra = new Lista<Articulo>();
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, amigo!

Answer (score 4):

Es porque al declarar los objetos

```
static Lista listacompra = new Lista<Articulo>();
static Lista listarticulos = new Lista<Articulo>();
```

static Lista listacompra ... no le estas diciendo que tipo le vas a asignar y el lo toma como Object
si lo colocas

```
static Lista<Articulo> listacompra = new Lista<Articulo>();
static Lista<Articulo> listarticulos = new Lista<Articulo>();
```

con eso ya no debes castear

Comment: Mil gracias amigo!

Answer (score 4):

Puedes declarar especificando el tipo de clase que contiene tu Lista en tu caso es `Articulo`: para que ya no te devuelva Object

```
static Lista<Articulo> listarticulos = new Lista<Articulo>();
```

pero seria mucha redundancia asi que basta con:

```
static Lista<Articulo> listarticulos = new Lista<>();
```